# Pushing the data in an array on success response of an AJAX call leads to appending the last data multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, response

I am trying to just append the data in an array on success response of file uploading.
Within the loop console is giving the correct output but the resultant array consists of replicated data(last data is repeated n times)

```
 data : consists of multiple file data that has to be uploaded
```

example :

FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
0: File {name: "demoform1.pdf", lastModified: 1565685422300, lastModifiedDate: Tue Aug 13 2019 14:07:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 20061, …}
1: File {name: "dummy.pdf", lastModified: 1565260694049, lastModifiedDate: Thu Aug 08 2019 16:08:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 13264, …}
length: 2

Method :

```
 uploadToServer(data) {
for ( let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {

  const fileType = this.fileValidations.getFileExtension(data[i].name);
  const filetype = {file_type : fileType};
  const data1 = {file : data[i]};
  let uploadFormData;
  uploadFormData = (Object as any).assign({}, data1, filetype);

  this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(uploadFormData).subscribe(res => {
    this.documentCount = this.documentCount + 1;

    const currentFileName = data[i].name;
    this.documentDetailsObj.name = res.original_name;
    this.documentDetailsObj.id = res.id;
    this.documentNameArr.push((this.documentDetailsObj));


    console.log(this.documentNameArr);

    // Expected output : 
    // 0: {name: "pdf1.pdf", id: 1}
    // 1: {name: "pdf2.pdf", id: 2}

    // Current Output :
    // 0: {name: "pdf2.pdf", id: 2}
    // 1: {name: "pdf2.pdf", id: 2}





  }, error => {
    console.log('error');
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Try `this.documentNameArr.push({...this.documentDetailsObj});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are passing the object in next iteration the same object is updated by pass by reference.

```
this.documentDetailsObj.name = res.original_name;
this.documentDetailsObj.id = res.id;
this.documentNameArr.push((this.documentDetailsObj));
```

You can just create an object and push it in one line no need of extra variables

```
this.documentNameArr.push({name: res.original_name, id: res.id});
```